# CSS Rounded corners for table header with background-color

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table with rounded top corners and a different background color for the header line. I succeeded in making both individually (super beginner in html/css) thanks to online ressources but I fail when it comes to have the two at the same time.

What I mean is (and you can see it in the fiddle below), I can round the corners just fine and have the design I want for my table except that the header background-color is still a perfect rectangle and thus is overflowing outside the rounded corners.

I tried adding the border-radius property in various places but none worked the way I intended. How can I make the corners rounded and having the thead background-color fitting nicely in it ?

```css
table.std {
  margin-top: 0.2cm;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0.03cm solid #8a8a8a;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

table.std thead {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 25px;
}

table.std thead tr th:first-child {
  padding-left: 0.25cm;
  /* To align with section title */
  border-bottom: 0.03cm solid #8a8a8a;
}

table.std tbody tr td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0.25cm;
  /* To align with section title */
  width: 30%;
}

table.std tbody tr td {
  border-bottom: 0.01cm dashed lightgray;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="std">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=2>Test</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>id1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>2019/12/19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem</td>
        <td>ipsum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>john</td>
        <td>doe</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/co7xb42n/

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

Add the border-radius to th

```
table.std thead tr th:first-child {
    padding-left: 0.25cm; /* To align with section title */
    border-bottom: 0.03cm solid #8a8a8a;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/53eshg64/

Answer (score 4):

add `border-radius` from `th` tag.

```css
table.std {
    margin-top: 0.2cm;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0.03cm solid #8a8a8a;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

table.std thead {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 25px;
}

table.std thead tr th:first-child {
    padding-left: 0.25cm; /* To align with section title */
    border-bottom: 0.03cm solid #8a8a8a;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

table.std tbody tr td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0.25cm; /* To align with section title */
    width: 30%;
}

table.std tbody tr td {
    border-bottom: 0.01cm dashed lightgray;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
                <table class="std">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan=2>Test</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>id1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Date</td>
                            <td>2019/12/19</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>foo</td>
                            <td>bar</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>lorem</td>
                            <td>ipsum</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>john</td>
                            <td>doe</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is cause the th tag is above of the table tag and it doesn't have any border-radius

Add the border-radius to th